# why does java and c# differ in simple Addition

Tags: java, c#

I have two snippets, one in **Java** and one in **c#**.

```
float a = 1234e-3f;
float b = 1.23f;
float ca = 1.234e3f;
float d = 43.21f;
long e = 1234L;
int f = 0xa;
int g = 014;
char h = 'Z';
char ia = ' ';


byte j = 123;
short k = 4321;

System.out.println(a+b+ca+d+e+f+g+h+ia+j+k);
```

the **Java** snippet returns **7101.674**

and in **c#**

```
float a = 1234e-3f;
float b = 1.23f;
float ca = 1.234e3f;
float d = 43.21f;
long e = 1234L;
int f = 0xa;
int g = 014;
char h = 'Z';
char ia = ' ';


byte j = 123;
short k = 4321;

Console.WriteLine(a+b+ca+d+e+f+g+h+ia+j+k);
```

produces a result of **7103.674**.

why am I *off* by **2** and what is correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is in the

```
int g = 014;
```

It's **Octal** in case of Java (`014 == 12`) and **Decimal** in case of C# (`014 == 14`).